# Android Smart Glasses Design Patterns

Tags: android, google-glass

I'm going to do some exploratory work about the realization of apps for smart glasses devices like Google Glass (which we don't own yet) and the Vuzix M100, and obviously such devices offers great potential, but also poses some great challenge.

One above all, the lack of extended user input interfaces: no touch, and extremely limited physical buttons.

So, I'm looking for resources about guidelines, design patterns, etc, but there seems to be few resources yet on the web.

Can someone point me to useful and relevant resources, specifically about this kind of devices?

I already have plenty of documentation about "classical" Android development.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Considering that this whole space is only a few months old, I would be stunned if there are any "resources about guidelines, design patterns, etc" at this point in time.

Comment: Of course, but event an on-going effort would be of great help. All I found are some sparse bit of information, but maybe there's some forum/wiki/blog I'm not still aware of.

Answer (score 1):

The pages from Google on the Glass Mirror API contain portions that address overall [best practices for developing with the API](https://developers.google.com/glass/guidelines) and [some specific user interface guidelines](https://developers.google.com/glass/ui-guidelines).

In general, however, you're already beginning to think about it incorrectly if you approach it from the "classical" Android (or even smartphone in general) perspective. Glass is designed to be a different product that is meant to be used in different ways. While you *can* shoehorn some smartphone concepts in, approaching it with a more open mind might yield you better results.

Comment: Glass..."official" user experience seems to me to be more "social" oriented. 

I have to find more "professional" usage scenarios, so I'll probably need to go beyond the Google Mirror API, and write real Android Apps.

Also, I have to get started with a non-glass device (the Vuzix M100)  since 1) we don't have a glass and 2) we must be open to alternative smart glasses options. Probably we can develop some "mirror-esque" features to display information and basic user interaction, we'll have to dig deeper. Anyway, I'm just getting started, so I'm surely missing something, I'm here to learn!

Comment: The Mirror API can do a lot more than "social". It is not as interactive as most people are expecting... but as you point out, the UI poses challenges on that front in general, and the Mirror API attempts to address them.